# Java - HttpUrlConnection waiting for download to finish

Tags: java, http, youtube

I am trying to download a youtube video using the youtubeinmp3 api provided on their website but the issue is when I am trying to convert a song that isn't already in their library (meaning it hasn't been converted before), the site will begin converting this song into .mp3 format.

Now what is happening with my HTTPUrlConnection is that if the download link is already on the site, since it has been cached, then it runs perfectly but if the site has to perform the conversion, it goes through without waiting for the conversion - meaning I just get an error.

This is currently what I have:

```
        URL link = new URL("http://YouTubeInMP3.com/fetch/?video=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JbjtL7P9eI0&autostart=1");

        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(link.openStream());
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int n = 0;
        HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL("http://YouTubeInMP3.com/fetch/?video=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JbjtL7P9eI0&autostart=1").openConnection());
        System.out.println(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK);
        long completeFileSize = httpConnection.getContentLength();
        long downloadedFileSize = 0;
        //int currentProgress = 0;
        while (-1!=(n=in.read(buf)))
        {
            out.write(buf, 0, n);
            downloadedFileSize += n;
            final int currentProgress= (int) (downloadedFileSize * 100 / completeFileSize);
            System.out.println("current progress: "+currentProgress);

        }
        System.out.println("Finished");
        out.close();
        in.close();
        byte[] response = out.toByteArray();

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/Users/stephen/Desktop/test.mp3");
        fos.write(response);
        fos.close();
```

What I was thinking is finding a way to stop the execution of my program or make it run in a while loop so long as the website has not finished loading. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Share the error please

Comment: Well the output file will be blank and if I check `completeFileSize`, it returns `-1` if the file has to be converted

Answer (score 0):

You open the connection **twice** - once for getting stream, once for content length. If you **must** do that, you should accept -1 as correct value meaning: don't know yet.

Im this case just skip shpwing progress percent and do the download until finished.

**I recommend** using only 1 HttpUrlConnection - not two

Comment: That shouldn't be too big of an issue to fix but my problem is mainly the fact that because the website does not have the download link read when I open the connection, my program fails to get the video

Comment: Oh okay. So loop 20 times and while -1 == getContebtLength and sleep 5s in loop?